# playframework1.3 : How to generate javadoc?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using `play-1.3`, and I saw there's an `play javadoc` command, but it doesn't work for me. The command line tells me everything is done, and I should be able to read find the doc under `javadoc` directory. But there's nothing there, just an empty directory.

```
./play javadoc project_name
Generating Javadoc in /Users/xxx/play-1.3/project_name/javadoc...
Done! You can open /Users/xxx/play-1.3/project_name/javadoc/overview-tree.html in your browser.
```

Comment: There should be a couple of log files created in the log folder (`{application_path}/logs/javadoc.log` and `{application_path}/logs/javadoc.err`). It might be worth taking a look in them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be broken, you can change in the directory of the map and call the play javadoc command from there.

framework/pym/play/commands/javadoc.py does not use the app directory when constructing the javadoc command line:

```
javadoc_cmd = [javadoc_path, '@'+os.path.join('javadoc','javadocOptions'), '@'+os.path.join('javadoc','javadocFiles')]
```

The outdir variable is used earlier for creating the file and options for javadoc and seem to work here:

```
javadoc_cmd = [javadoc_path, '@'+os.path.join(outdir, 'javadocOptions'), '@'+os.path.join(outdir, 'javadocFiles')]
```

Comment: Good catch, have you filled a bug or pull-request yet?

Comment: Bug report with the findings is here, the SO question is mentioned too: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1864-play-javadoc-app-broken